# CSRF token mismatch

Tags: csrf-token, laravel-6.2

I really frustrating with this error, I have datatable with ajax post request, but the error CSRF token mismatch rarely appear.
this my jquery ajax post setup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

ajax:{
    "url": "trip/jsondata",
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "POST",
    "data" : function ( d ){
        d.nState= $('#viewoption').val(),
        d.nYear  = $('#viewyear').val();
    }
},
```

I courious why my post request return CSRF token mismatch, so I've modified the Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken file to return the token values like below.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (
        $this->isReading($request) ||
        $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->inExceptArray($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    ) {
        return tap($next($request), function ($response) use ($request) {
            if ($this->shouldAddXsrfTokenCookie()) {
                $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $response);
            }
        });
    }

    $error='getTokenFromRequest :'.$this->getTokenFromRequest($request).' | X-CSRF-TOKEN :'.$request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN').' | Session :'.$request->session()->token();
    throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch. err: '.$error);
}
```

I Try to return 3 variables (getTokenFromRequest, X-CSRF-TOKEN, and the Session token).
And the result is:

**message:** "CSRF token mismatch. err: getTokenFromRequest :**w0nxu5OPWZHFrBFqMtLsL3IWJ1vCg0VAGbCDt4c3** | X-CSRF-TOKEN :**w0nxu5OPWZHFrBFqMtLsL3IWJ1vCg0VAGbCDt4c3** | Session :**CiMUsbN9BumKIElvrOzJX8TnCA8UeuAAaLzbfZTO**"

You can see there is a different between X-CSRF-TOKEN with Session Token, I don't know why?

Then I try to check in the storage\framework\sessions folder, there are two files.
[image]

The first file filled like this 
**a:7:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"w0nxu5OPWZHFrBFqMtLsL3IWJ1vCg0VAGbCDt4c3";**

The second file filled like this
**a:2:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"CiMUsbN9BumKIElvrOzJX8TnCA8UeuAAaLzbfZTO";**

***Anyone can help what's happen in my application? is it normal have 2 sessions at the same time with a different token?***